# continuous integration tool for VS-built c# project

Tags: continuous-integration, infrastructure

We need to setup a continuous integration infrastructure for a C# project. None of us has anything other than a very few user-side experience with these tools at all.
Our requirements would be:

- we need a tool which runs on windows, because we want our project to be csc-built. Building with mono is not an option.
- we use an SVN server and it's on linux, it needs to be able to get the source from that.

Could anyone of you more experienced collagues recommend a tool like that? :) Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CruiseControl is a good choice. Have a look here: http://cruisecontrol.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Thank you man! It looks very nice. I'll check it out tomorrow, but anyway, I'd be glad to hear of any alternatives too.